# Rails + PostgreSQL group data hourly with datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, highcharts

I try to build data for chart like this:

https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/intraday-candlestick

Here is example data for this chart:

https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/new-intraday.json

So, I need to get data in this format from rails - need to group data hourly with additional timestamp.

How it can be realized via Rails 5 + Postgresql with default created_at column and any other custom column with data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by extracted hour from `created_at`, you will need to aggregate all the other data that you want to display as well,

```
YourModel.select("EXTRACT(hour FROM created_at) AS hour_created_at")
         .group("hour_created_at")
```

You can access the hour by calling `.hour_created_at` on each of the returned objects.

You may want to chain `.order("hour_created_at")` to properly iterate over the results.

Comment: Something is wrong for me here :( 
`MyModel.where(link_id: 2).select("value, EXTRACT(hour FROM created_at) AS hour_created_at").group("hour_created_at")` gives me PSQL error: 
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "my_models.value" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`)

Comment: Yup, as I mentioned you will need to aggregate all the other returned columns. You can't simply return `value` for all `YourModels` from a specific hour as there are multiple rows being aggregated into that, you may change your `value` in select to `SUM(value) as values_sum` or apply any other aggregation that you need, see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html)